# Fresh new tern install on eclipse do not run

Tags: eclipse, tern

Just installed ternjs IDE on fresh new Eclipse JEE.

The problem is that I can not get it working.

Any code edit or even mouse click inside editor window cause console errors like this one:

```
\plugins\ternjs_1.1.0.201511082254\node_modules\tern\lib\def.js:85 
Error: Unrecognized type spec: !0. (at 3) at Object.TypeParser.error
```

Tern configuration is simple, just for meteor

```
.tern-project: {
  "ecmaVersion": 5,
 "plugins": {
 "guess-types": {

},
"outline": {

},
"meteor": {     
}
},
"libs": [
 "browser"
]
}
```

The same problem for both local and system nodejs.

Any ideas?

Comment: Have you tried to install tern.java 1.2.0-SNAPSHOT (not released)? Otherwise please share your project.

Comment: @Angelo have the same:  .......soft\eclipse_Mars_jee_tern\plugins\ternjs_1.2.0.201601182201\node_modules\tern\lib\def.js:85
      throw new Error("Unrecognized type spec: " + this.spec + " (at " + this.pos + ")");'
      ^

Comment: Please share your project.

Comment: It's not so easy ... but it's simple meteor project, as for now.

Comment: why not sharing your project on github?

Comment: I am not owner of the code, can not share it. Will try to arrange other testing code.

Comment: Have you already installed tern.java? If yes, could you create a new workspcae and retry it? If you remove meteor, is it working?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/101167/discussion-between-paul-paku-and-angelo).